# How to use jQuery datatable 1.10 in ASP to refresh the table after successful insertion?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

My datatable lionization code is here:

```
function FnRetrieveSuccess(result) {
        $res = JSON.parse(result.d);
        console.log(result.d);
        $("#tblData tbody").empty();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $res.length; $i++) {
            $("#tblData tbody").append("<tr id=" + $res[$i].ID + " style='cursor:pointer'><td>" + $res[$i].ID + "</td><td>" + $res[$i].Name + "</td><td>" + $res[$i].ServeceArea + "</dt><td>" + $res[$i].Admin_type + "</td><td><a  class='fa fa-pencil'></a><a style='color:red;margin-left:15px; 'class='fa fa-times' onclick='FnDeleteRow(" + $res[$i].ID + ")'></a></td></tr>");

        }
        if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tblData')) {
            table1 = $('#tblData').DataTable();
        }
        else {
            table1 = $("#tblData").DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "pageLength": 5,
                "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "ordering": true,
                "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 6, "orderable": false }],
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    $(nRow).attr("id", aData[0]);
                    return nRow;
                }


            });
        }

    }
```

And code for reload table is here, but it shows an error:

> TypeError: table1.fnDestroy is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
// It will reload the datatable by again calling the ajax of datatable
```

Comment: i try table1.DataTable().ajax.reload(); which not working

Comment: error is that  DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: TypeError: g is null
 

...,b,i,a):(a.jqXHR=h.ajax(h.extend(n,g)),g.data=f)}function lb(a){return a.bAjaxDa...

Answer (score 0):

```
 var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({"destroy": true});
```

now add the rows into Datatable

```
 table.row.add([row1,row2,row3,row4,row5]).draw(false);
```

add destroy attribute and try following code

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: it show no error but not refreshes the the table after insertion

Comment: table.row.add([row1,row2,row3,row4,]).draw(false); add the data using a method

Comment: function FnInsertSucces(result) {
        if (result.d == "Success") {
            console.log("data inserted");
            var table = $('#tblData').DataTable({ "destroy": true });
           table.ajax.reload();
            $("#name").val("");
            $("#uname").val("");
            $("#pwd").val("");
        }

Comment: I can not understand the flow. this is the function where i want to do the logic please set it for me